# Shared memory cache for non-serialized data

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, memcached

I have a (Django) web app that needs to construct large (numpy) arrays, let's say 1MB per vector. It works on several processes (spawned by Apache/mod_wsgi).

For the moment I am using **in-memory cache**, which simplest version is a global variable. Retrieving the data from cache is instantaneous - all I need. However, each process needs to replicate the cache in its own memory, and it is [unpredictable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200096/cache-randomly-removing-items/36200479?noredirect=1#comment60038283_36200479) which process has the data loaded and which hasn't (I want to load it once and for all at startup).

I tried **Memcached** and **Redis** to have a shared cache among processes. Both need the data to be serialized first: strings and ints only. Now, de-serializing when I want to read a vector takes about 10s, a bit long for a user waiting after clicking a button.

Isn't there any solution that can at the same time store some arbitrary data in RAM without serializing to string, and have it shared among different processes ? (I am not interested in persistence after restart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis supports many [data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types), including raw bytes

> Strings are the most basic kind of Redis value. **Redis Strings are
>   binary safe, this means that a Redis string can contain any kind of
>   data**, for instance a JPEG image or a serialized Ruby object.

Redis is proven to be fast, so maybe your focus should be on an efficient serialization format that deserializes quickly, e.g.

- https://github.com/lebedov/msgpack-numpy
- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#why-use-protocol-buffers
- http://slides.zetatech.org/haenel-bloscpack-talk-2014-PyDataBerlin.pdf

Comment: Keep in mind you can use the Redis SETRANGE command to modify arbitrary ranges of bytes with a string value and GETRANGE to fetch such substrings.  As with Python string (2.x) and bytearrays (3.x) these are binary safe.  So, as @simpsojo has said here, you can use these commands with various bulk serialization/deserialization options.  Conceptually this would be similar to treating the value stored at some key as a sort of mmap() region (a big, shared array of bytes).  However, Redis handles the co-ordination (no locking issues).

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if you agree?  Thanks